# gmaps cannot show figure in vscode (python)

Tags: python, google-maps, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a heatmap using `gmaps`. So far my code is

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import gmaps 
gmaps.configure(api_key="AI...")
gmaps.figure((40.75, -74.00),2)
```

which only prints ("This site didnt load Google Maps correctly") [image: Error message].

I have set up a billing account, enabled Maps Javascript, and I can see in my Google Cloud Project that the API key is used (13 calls - 13 errors but I cannot see the error in Google Cloud Platform).

Further more I have run `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` and tried in jupyter notebook (both in VSCode and in the browser) and in the "python interactive window".

Answer (score 2):

I ended up removing `nbextensions` and then install [this](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator), and now the error is gone!

Comment: wow I've been trying to get this to work for years and it finally works! Thank you!
Small edit, you now have to pass these arguments as keyword args: eg ```gmaps.figure(center=(40.75, -74.00),zoom_level=2)```